# Linking tabular data by condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data that has students names (columns), dates (rows), and the table is populated with a variety of 0's and grades (values > 0). For a given date there may > 0 grades under some students names and 0's under others.

What I'm trying to do, on a separate worksheet, is generate a 3-column list (as long as it needs to be to list all the > 0 values with the columns being arranged by date, student name, and grade). Again, I only want to pull values that are > 0, not have a row of blanks or zeros in the list when a 0 is found in the table. I can't seem to figure out how to do this easily with the built-in worksheet functions so I was hoping someone could provide some suggestions (worksheet functions preferably but I'm also open to a snipped of VBA code). The fact that there are 0's somewhat randomly interspersed in the matrix is tripping up any fancy/clever logic I've been able to come up with. The matrix size is approximately 20 students by a few hundred dates, just FYI.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Could you provide me with a sample (a short/small one, say, 6 dates by 4 students) of a "main" table with some 0's and some not, and a "desired list of 0's" extracted from this sample of the "main" table, please?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the steps detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651), convert the Table to Range, filter ColumnC to select `0` and `(Blanks)`, delete all visible apart from the header.